# How can i add back stack to my tab layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

In my project i have used View Page adapter to my tab layout, unable to add back stack to the tab layout

How can i add the back stack to my tab layout

i have used android studio for this project

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
            viewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            ViewPageAdapter adapter =new 
            ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.AddFragment(new BlankFragment(),"first");
            adapter.AddFragment(new BlankFragment2(),"second");
            adapter.AddFragment(new BlankFragment3(),"third");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

need to get the backstacks for the tab layout

Comment: what exactly do you mean by add backstack? what according to you should happen?

Comment: for example if i have clicked on third (tab or fragemnt) first and second (tab or fragment) next to third ,now i need backstack when i click on back button the second tab should disappear and must open the previous one(Third tab)

Comment: That would be a bad way to implement the tab layout , suppose if user goes back and forth 10 times between tabs , then user have to click back 10 times to go to back screen/quit app

Comment: @ManoharReddy i think we can use pop backstack so that there is no need for 10 times to go back ?is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle back button at onBackPressed() method like this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
       if(viewPager.currentItem > 0){
            viewPager.currentItem = viewPager.currentItem - 1
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
}
```

Comment: if i go to third tab first and second tab next and click on back button it goes to the first tab but not to the third tab ???

Comment: i think this is bad user experience

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is save the tab positions in list 
 when user switched tab . Navigate user to particular tab and remove element from list when he clicks back ,  until there are no elements in the list.

Also make sure you don't have duplicate positions in saved list so user won't go to the same tabs when pressing back .

Just saying again , that would be a bad way to implement the tab layout . Users generally won't expect to go to previous tab when clicking back button . They expect to go to previous screen / exit app .